# Most javascript frameworks have components with "data down, callback up" interface, what is the equivalent of this in Sencha ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have experience with Angular/Ember/React and in every of these frameworks you have a clear notion of component that accepts argument as initial data and callbacks as reference to the parent (I believe in Ember its called "Data down, action up"). I tried to learn ExtJS but i dont see what should i use as equivalent of this interface, how communication between nested components should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common pattern in Ext for passing initial data is through an object parameter. The properties of the passed object correspond to a [config object in the class definition](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-config).

Ext automatically creates getter and setter methods for all properties in the config object, as well as [apply and update methods](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171113-Difference-between-update-and-apply-magic-methods) for transforming values before and after they're set.

For communication between components, you can wire up [listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.mixin.Observable.html#cfg-listeners) that handle events fired from the nested component. The events can be standard provided by Ext (such as 'click' fired from an [Ext.button.Button](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#event-click)) or custom ones you make up and send using [fireEvent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-fireEvent).

Another way of communicating between components is to use the parent's [view model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) and the component's [bind config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.mixin.Bindable.html#cfg-bind).

View models come with the benefit of being [visible by all descendant components](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html), so child components can bind to a view model property, which if not found on the child component itself, will be propagated up the chain of ancestors until a matching view model property is found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initial data

   •  In Ext JS every component accepts a JSON object as its initial config data.

   •  You can even set the configs at [initComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-initComponent) method associated with every component you create. The initComponent template method is an important initialization step for a Component.  The initComponent method of the class being created is called first, with each initComponent method up until the hierarchy to Ext.Component being called thereafter. This makes it easy to implement and, if needed, override the constructor logic of the Component at any step in the hierarchy.

   `Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    html: 'Hello world!',
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    padding: 20,
    style: {
       color: '#FFFFFF',
       backgroundColor:'#000000'
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
   });`
2. Data Communication between components.

   •  In Ext JS communication between components is via event ([listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.mixin.Observable.html#cfg-listeners) and fireEvent with listen config).

   •  Communication can be also between child and parent ViewModels. The most commonly used aspect of a ViewModel is the bind method. This method takes a "bind descriptor" and a callback to call when the data indicated by the bind descriptor either becomes available or changes.

Every component can be associated with ViewModel and Controller. These are the most commonly used once.